# LC3 - Can anyone help me with this Assignment?

Tags: lc3

Extremely stuck on this assignment

Here is what I have to do:

[image: Picture of the assignment]

So far I have gotten to line 3, Currently stuck on line 4,5,6 and 7

The code I have done so far is this:

```
.orig   x3000
Lea r1, storeString

Lea r0, PrintStudent
puts

Lea r0, EnterText
puts

LOOP
getc

out
str r0, r1, 0
add r1, r1, 1
add r0, r0, -10

brz OUTSIDE

brnzp LOOP

OUTSIDE

Lea r0, UserEnter
puts

Lea r0, storeString
puts

Halt
PrintStudent .stringz "Francois Van Zyl"
EnterText .stringz "\nPlease enter a text: "
UserEnter .stringz "\nThe text you have typed is: "
storeString .blkw 99

.end
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to check spaces and characters, you need to compare ASCII values.

E.G. If the difference between a character you are checking for and the value for a spacebar are the same, then the result is zero. So if you check a character, say 'A;, and subtract that the value for a spacebar, the difference would not be 0 because 'A' is not an empty space.

Tip: You'll want to use the branching instruction and a counters to loop through and keep track of amount of space, capitals, etc, as well as one for your position.